# Why not to calculate the limit of individual terms when the number of terms approach infinity due to limiting variable?

Tags: calculus, limits

My instructor was using this example to illustrate his point-

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+2+3+...+n}{n^2}$$
The numerator is an AP and the limit can be easily calculated this way to be a finite number($0.5$ in this case).

But, if we use the sum law and separate all the $\frac{r}{n^2}$ terms, the individual limits will be $0$ and so will be the answer. This is what my instructor told me to avoid.

My question is-

1. Why can we not do this?
2. Should we also not do this if the individual limits are finite values?
3. Is this specific to the sum law?

Comment: One of the reasons is that every time you have more and more terms/summands in the numerator which you can't control. In such cases we use either the squeeze theorem or, e. g., Stolz-Cesaro.

Comment: $$\frac{1+1+\cdots+1}n$$ with $n$ ones on the top illustrates the same point in an even simpler way.

Comment: See tha answer by Paramanand Singh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum law, or any of the other limit laws, is usually stated only for the case of 2 terms.  By induction, we may extend it to 3, 4, 5, or any other *fixed* finite number of terms, where *fixed* means that the number does not depend on the limit variable $n$. However, as your example shows, we may not extend it to the case where the number of terms depends on $n$.

Comment: Yes, we can.  We can also extend it to any fixed, finite combination of sums, products, etc.